# Как вывести на сайт список пользователей онлайн в TeamSpeak3

Tags: веб-программирование

Если сервер TS3 в котором сидят пользователи по комнатам. Как на сайте в реальном времени отображать всех пользователей онлайн?

P.S.: Я знаю, что существуют модули для администрирования ТС и тому подобное. Но мне надо получить только список пользователей без всяких других наворотов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В TeamSpeak 3 PHP Framework есть возможность вывод пользователей на сервере.
Документация https://docs.planetteamspeak.com/ts3/php/framework/index.html

```
<?php

require_once("libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php");

$ts3_VirtualServer = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://username:password@127.0.0.1:10011/?server_port=9987");

$arr_ClientList = $ts3_VirtualServer->clientList();

print_r($arr_ClientList);

?>
```

p.s Не проверял но в теории должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо спасибо огромнющее :) выручили девушку :)

Comment: Если на сервере TS несколько виртуальных TS серверов, то в при подключении в $ts3_VirtualServer нужно дополнительно прописать serverID в стиле "&server_id=1". P.S. а clientList() выводит информацию в таком виде, что лучше бы не выводил ))

Answer (score 1):

Есть специальный протокол для TeamSpeak сервера, который называется Server Query.
[Документация на английском](http://media.teamspeak.com/ts3_literature/TeamSpeak%203%20Server%20Query%20Manual.pdf)

Если быть конкретнее, то,насколько я понял, вас интересует комнада:

**CLIENTLIST**

Comment: спасибо, похоже на правду, буду разбираться :)

Comment: А можно кусочек кода который подключается к серверу и использует данную команду? а то не особо понимаю как использовать данную команду, это на php?